# ASP MVC Radio Button - Not select a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

In a view I have a Radio Button whith 2 options:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary ">
                <input value="0" name="Gender" type="radio"> Feminino
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary ">
                <input value="1" name="Gender" type="radio"> Masculino
            </label>
</div>
```

When I post this without select any value in my model I receive 0 (zero) on gender field. This have to be null or something like that and invalidate my model. Because the user must choose a value.

```
public enum Genero
    {
        Feminino = 0,
        Masculino = 1
    }

public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public Genero? Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
{...}
```

Model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Gender")]
public Genero Gender { get; set; }
```

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: Make you property nullable -`public Genero? Gender { get; set; }` and add the `[Required]` attribute

Comment: Stephen, I put public Genero? Gender { get; set; } and [Required] and nothing change.

Comment: I change my model and it's work! Tanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my entitie class to:

```
public Genero? Gender { get; set; }
```

And my view model to:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Gender")]
public Genero? Gender { get; set; }
```

Tanks for comments.

Comment: Don't post your answer by your self which is solved by someone's suggestion

Comment: I just want close the post. How I procedure?

Comment: @MarcusBraga, Its fine for you to add your own answer if no one has added one. Just click the tick mark to accept it.